# Pip literal version constraints

Tags: python, pip, versioning

Info: I am using a tool that other team provided: **delivery**. I am adding some more code to it and before pip 20.3 I have packed it as **delivery-local-1.5-py3-none-any.whl**.
and  I was installing my tool from PyPi as

```
pip install delivery==local-1.5
```

Can you, please tell me what should I do after pip 20.3? It does not work like that even though my versions are in the list.

Comment: Maybe use the [_"arbitrary equality" version specifier_](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#arbitrary-equality): `pip install 'delivery===local-1.5'`.

Comment: @sinoroc what if I wiill want to update to the latest version? to run pip install delivery==local?

Comment: I do not think you can. -- Maybe what you can do instead is to pick better version strings for your own builds. Maybe something with [_Local version segments_](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#local-version-segments). Or simply use [_Post-releases_](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#post-releases) suffixes.